# Run Spark on GKE vs Dataproc on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, spark-structured-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

We are planning to move our Spark Structured Streaming jobs from Cloudera to GCP. My question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455729/gcp-spark-on-gke-vs-dataproc). But since it has been a while that the question is active, we are wondering if there are any advantages of running DataProc on GKE? And are there production deployments that installs and manages Spark directly on GKE without Dataproc.

Cost is of a concern (like most places :)) and the assumption is that it would be cheaper to run Spark on GKE with out Dataproc.

PS: We have other applications and datastores running on GKE.